# Function template: why ambiguity is generated?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following simple function template:

max.hpp:

```
template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
   return a <b? b :a;
}
```

max.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "max.hpp"

int main()
{
  int i = 42;
  std::cout << "max(7,i): " << ::max(7,i) << std::endl;

  double f1 = 3.4;
  double f2 = -6.7;
  std::cout << "max(f1,f2): "<< ::max(f1,f2) << std::endl;

  std::string s1 = "mathematics";
  std::string s2 = "math";
  std::cout << "max(s1,s2): " << ::max(s1,s2) << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

This works fine, since `::` will tell compiler to search for `max` template in global namespace. However, when I remove those `::` in those 3 cases, I got the following ambiguity error message:

```
max.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
max.cpp:21:43: error: call of overloaded ‘max(std::string&, std::string&)’ is ambiguous                                            
max.hpp:2:17: note: candidates are: const T& max(const T&, const T&) 
 [with T = std::basic_string<char>]                                          
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:209:5: 
note: const  _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) 
[with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>]
```

My questions are as follows:

1. In this case, does the compiler search for `std` namespace by default even I did not include the header file `<algorithm>` where `std::max` is located?
2. What are placed in the `global namespace`? Is it required to use the `::` when calling functions in `global namespace` under all circumstances?
3. Why there is no ambiguity when `max` is applied on `integer` and `float` type, only has ambiguity for `string` type?

FYI: I am using gcc 4.5.3 for compiling.
Thank you!

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Yes, I am sure. I just did a double check, the code posted is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this case, does the compiler search for std namespace by default
>   even I did not include the header file  where std::max is
>   located?

Yes, this is called [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). Note that the header file in which `std::max` is defined might be included by some file you included.

> What are placed in the global namespace? Is it required to use the ::
>   when calling functions in global namespace under all circumstances?

No, only when there's ambiguity. This is one of those cases.

> Why there is no ambiguity when max is applied on integer and float
>   type, only has ambiguity for string type?

Because neither `int` nor `float` are defined in namespace `std`. Therefore the compiler does not look inside that namespace and as a consequence `std::max` is not considered during overload resolution. This is not the case of `std::string`.

Note that you could trigger the same ambiguity if you did:

```
using namespace std;
```

Or:

```
using std::max;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. These helped a lot on understanding this topic, especially for the Koenig lookup one.

Answer (score 1):

The other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725798/241631) explains why the ambiguity arises because of ADL. One way to avoid it is to qualify the call to `max` (in this case using `::` to restrict the name lookup to the global namespace).

Another, perhaps more obscure, method to restrict ADL is to use the following syntax

```
std::cout << "max(s1,s2): " << (max)(s1,s2) << std::endl; 
//                             ^   ^
```

The following example [compiles](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4Ucxw$7) without errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
   return a < b ? b : a;
}

int main()
{
  std::string s1("mathematics");
  std::string s2("math");
  std::cout << "max(s1,s2): " << (max)(s1,s2) << std::endl;
}
```